# Trying to find + character in wordpress query using wp_query with s parameter

Tags: wordpress

I use wp_query to try to find + character in the title of item in my database using 's' =>item+8%2B6 but no luck...i get no results. Is it possible? any help appreciated. + is equal to %2B ...

```
?s=item+8%2B6
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to decode the [urldecode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) function if require